# Two questions about bash commands / Linux

Tags: linux, bash, command, kernel, vi

I need answers for those questions:

1. How and where can I change default app in user profile in Linux?
2. How can I save changes in vi editor without exiting? I guess it's w q q! but I'm not sure.

Comment: 1. are you about `man xdg-settings`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How and where can I change default app in user profile in Linux?

I guess you refer to the editor. If so, use the following:

```
export EDITOR=vi #or whatever other editor
```

To make it permanent, add this line to the `.bashrc` file in the home of the user, that is in `~/.bashrc`.

---

> How can I save changes in vi editor without exiting? I guess it's w q q! but I'm not sure.

use `:w` to save. You have to be in the command mode (go there pushing <kbd>Esc</kbd>).

Comment: thx fedorqui

Anyone with the 1st one?

Comment: Just updated answering the 1st, @MateuszOsuch

Comment: So, I need to put "export EDITOR=vi" in /home/user/.bash_profile ?

Comment: To make it permanent, yes, @MateuszOsuch.

Comment: And if I don't want to make it permanent? I mean where should I place id?

Comment: Then just execute the line `export EDITOR=vi` manually. If it is in `bashrc` it will be executed every time the user logs in the terminal.